# How to avoid duplicates using PostgreSQL's BETWEEN for timestamps in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, between

I have a query in my Rails app that looks like this. Essentially, I want to get the records that were created between 9:30am yesterday and 9:30am today. I intend to use this query in a task that runs once every day.

```rb
last_execution_time = Time.zone.parse("#{Time.zone.yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} 09:30:00}")
this_execution_time = Time.zone.parse("#{Time.zone.today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} 09:30:00}")

new_cat_records = Cat.where(created_at: last_execution_time..this_execution_time)
```

However, I am concerned about what would happen to a record created at exactly 9:30:00 am. If I ran this query today and tomorrow, would it be included both times?
I know that PostgreSQL's `BETWEEN` includes the range boundaries ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html)):

> The BETWEEN predicate simplifies range tests:
>
> ```
> a BETWEEN x AND y
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> a >= x AND a <= y
> ```
>
> Notice that BETWEEN treats the endpoint values as included in the range.

If the code above would potentially cause duplicates, how can I avoid this?

- Should I change the time in `this_execution_time` to `9:29:59`?
- Or are there more granular things to take into consideration, like milliseconds?

---

**[Edit]** I use `rails 5.2.3` and `pg 1.1.4`.

Comment: You can write a query which has last_execution_time > 9:30(yesterday) and this_execution_time <= 9:30(today).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could query like :

```
Cat.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?", last_execution_time, this_execution_time)
```

or

```
Cat.where("created_at > ? AND created_at <= ?", last_execution_time, this_execution_time)
```

I'm not sure if this will impact performances though.

Comment: Your solution resulted in this: `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "<"`. Is it possible that you have to use some other syntax for chaining besides `&&`?

Comment: Actually, just figured it out myself - it was `AND`. Like this: `Cat.where("cats.created_at >= ? AND cats.created_at < ?", last_execution_time, this_execution_time)`

Comment: Oh yes my bad i'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have small problem with boundary conditions if you use `between` with 09:30:00..09:30:00

You can change `this_execution_time` this way with milliseconds :

```
this_execution_time = Time.zone.parse("#{Time.zone.today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} 09:29:59.999999}")
```

Or you can use Arel or clean sql to write correct conditions:

```
Cat.where(Cat.arel_table[:created_at].gteq(last_execution_time).and(Cat.arel_table[:created_at].lt(this_execution_time)))
Cat.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?", last_execution_time, this_execution_time)
```

But be better if you write some boundary condition tests and check it there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much Rails, done some reading but that's all, but I do know a little Postgres - maybe it'll help. Postgres has a concept of [intervals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT) which allows setting up a structure like BETWEEN but also allows defining whether the endpoints are included or not. In this case include the start_time and exclude the end_time. The below creates such an interval:

```
with date_period as 
     ( select current_date + interval '9:30:00' d1
            , current_date + interval '1 day' + interval '9:30:00' d2
     ) 
   , op_dates as 
     ( SELECT generate_series(current_date, current_date+interval '2 day', interval '.5 hours') run_dt)
select  run_dt
  from op_dates
     , date_period
 where 1=1
   and run_dt <@ tsrange(d1, d2, '[)');
```

Read the AND predicate in the where clause as "run date is contained within the range d1 and d2, include d1 but exclude d2". What you want is to include that predicate into your where in place of the between predicate. You could change the tsrange function to (d1, d2, '(]'). That would exclude the beginning of the range (d1) but include the end of the range (d2)

To compare I'll include the query for BETWEEN with the same generated data;

```
with date_period as 
     ( select current_date + interval '9:30:00' d1
            , current_date + interval '1 day' + interval '9:30:00' d2
     ) 
   , op_dates as 
     ( SELECT generate_series(current_date, current_date+interval '2 day', interval '.5 hours') run_dt)
select run_dt
  from op_dates
     , date_period
 where 1=1
   and run_dt between d1 and d2;
```

Comment: Looking at other replies, maybe try. If I got the syntax correct "Cat.where("created_at  <@ tsrange( ?, ? , '?') last_execution_time, this_execution_time. '[)')"